# Event and Task input fields are not displaying on sites URL for sandbox

Tags: force.com-sites, site.com

I am not able to see fields of event & task (Activity) in sites that i have created.
I already check all of the permission for each fields as well and from sites i checked Public Access Setting too (It is OK.)
but don't know why i am not able to see.

Thanks

```
    <apex:form id="theOne">
      <apex:pageMessages />
      <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
              <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!Save}" rerender="theOne"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:pageblocksection >
              <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Name :"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!event.Name__c}"/>
              </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
              <apex:outputLabel />
              <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Business Name :"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!event.Business_Name__c}"/>
              </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
              <apex:outputLabel />
              <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Telephone Number :"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!event.Telephone_Number__c}"/>
              </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
              <apex:outputLabel />
              <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Email Id :"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!event.Email_Id__c}"/>
              </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
              <apex:outputLabel />
              <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Reason For The Call :"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!event.Reason_For_The_Call__c}"/>
              </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
              <apex:outputLabel />
              <apex:pageblockSectionItem id="pbsectionitem">
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Select Date:"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!event.ActivityDate}"/>  
              </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
              <div id="datepicker" />
              <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Time Slot :"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!event.Time_Slot__c}"/>
              </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
              <apex:outputLabel />
              <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Notes & Comments :"/>
                  <apex:inputfield value="{!event.Description}"/>
              </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
          </apex:pageblocksection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
```

[image]

Comment: Nihar, can u add a screenshot of what you see and the VF page code you have.. does the same VF page display the fields internally ?

Comment: yes. i can see all fields internally.

Comment: Vamsi Krishna, I have edited my question with screenshot and code. can you please tell what happens wrong ?